# Can anybody know the reason why the blog(from github pages) displays wrong in the github but ok in local?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

My blog [url](http://daicoolb.github.io/Beili/)

I have choosen a template from [Github](https://github.com/lay1010/lay1010.github.io)

I have installed jekyll successfully in Ubuntu and used the command "jekyll server" to test the blog which displays ok .
[here is the successful image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1HX5.png)

[image]

But when I commit it to the github ,it displays wrong ,I don't know the reason .
[here is the wrong image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCgWb.png)

[image]

My code is in the github. Below is the [url](http://github.com/daicoolb/Beili)

Can anybody find the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: your blog url http://daicoolb.github.io/Beili/ does display correctly from Europe.

If you don't see the CSS in action, that means some javascript/css resources are blocked (like [`jsquery.js` hosted by Google](https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/issues/3954))

The [OP Beili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5624422/beili) found out why it worked locally, not on GitHub:

> When we want to use a css file , we always use a form like "`/docs/sth.css`".
> But when we commit our files to github-pages, we must add the blog url before the form like this "`{{site.baseurl}}/docs/sth.css`".

Comment: Thanks for your time . I have find the cause that my url is not correct . It works when I change it .

Comment: @Beili good catch. Do you mean your web page source included an incorrect url?

Comment: Sorry I am poor in english but I will try to express it clearly .  When we want to use a css file , we always use  a form like "/docs/sth.css" . But when commit our files to  github-pages , you must add the bolg's url before the form like this "{{site.baseurl}}/docs/sth.css"

Comment: @Beili Excellent! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.